# rpi-benchmark seems to have crashed my system: SMP : failed to stop secondary CPUs after running

Tags: crash, smp

For analysis / benchmarking, I ran https://github.com/aikoncwd/rpi-benchmark

I ran rpi-benchmark on 3 pi's, 2 x model "1" and 1 model "2"

On the model 1 it ran OK.

On the model 2, it crashed my system. It ran OK, but immediately after that I got segfaults, and after reboot I get SMP errors: SMP : failed to stop secondary CPUs after running rpi-benchmark

Anyone familiar with this???

Thanks, Pla

[image: view kernel error picture]

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem? I had a similar message happen to a client (not running benchmark) and no clue why this happens was his first boot sequence on a known good image (hundreds of other clients no problem)

Comment: Hello Trevor, I can not recall 'solving' the issue itself. I do know that almost all my problems seemed related to big Micro-SD cards. Check this post to read further: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119433/slow-pi-running-pihole-due-to-large-microsd-with-only-one-partition/119500#119500

Comment: I got this same error after installing the RetroPie OS on a 4 GB SD using Raspberry Pi Imager. Not knowing what to do I just re-wrote the SD card and started again and the second time it did not occur.